# Assign values from array to a HTML element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML i have 4 image tags like this

```
  <div id="imgContainer">
    <img id = "crystal1" src="assets/images/crystal1.jpg" alt="crystal1">
    <img id = "crystal2" src="assets/images/crystal2.jpg" alt="crystal2">
    <img id = "crystal3" src="assets/images/crystal3.jpg" alt="crystal3">
    <img id = "crystal4" src="assets/images/crystal4.jpg" alt="crystal4">
  </div>
```

in my JS file i have this function which picks 4 random values between 1-12 and pushes them into a global array.

```
function generateCrystalNumber(){
for (var i = 0; i<4; i++){
crystalNumvar = Math.floor(Math.random()*12) + 1;
crystalNumbers.push(crystalNumvar);
```

}

}

How do I go about assigning each of the values in the array to a different image tag using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning each of the values in the array to a different image tag"? What are you trying to accomplish doing this? The word 'assigning' is a bit broad here

Comment: @KyleBecker lets say my function picks 1, 5, 12, 7 as my numbers, i would like for each image tag to have one of those numbers as a value. Im going to make the images clickable so when the user clicks on an image they get whatever value is assigned to it

Comment: @iamdio please see my updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function and loop over your images, add attribute using [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

You can get rid of the array and generate random numbers within the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*12) + 1;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('data-crystal', getRandomInt());
    });
});
```

```js
var crystalNumbers = [];
    function generateCrystalNumber() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            crystalNumvar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
            crystalNumbers.push(crystalNumvar);
        }
    }
    generateCrystalNumber();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('img').each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr('data-crystal', crystalNumbers[index]);
        })
        
        $('img').on('click', function(){
            console.log($(this).attr('data-crystal'));
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgContainer">
    <img id="crystal1" src="assets/images/crystal1.jpg" alt="crystal1">
    <img id="crystal2" src="assets/images/crystal2.jpg" alt="crystal2">
    <img id="crystal3" src="assets/images/crystal3.jpg" alt="crystal3">
    <img id="crystal4" src="assets/images/crystal4.jpg" alt="crystal4">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked flawlessly and I actually understand whats going on except for the     $(document).ready(function () {} . I understood it as something you use once to wrap all of the js/jquery, i'm going to refer to the documentation to understand it further. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateCrystalNumber(){
var crystalNumbers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<4; i++){
    crystalNumvar = Math.floor(Math.random()*12) + 1;
    crystalNumbers.push(crystalNumvar); 
  }
  document.getElementById('imgContainer').childNodes.forEach(function(elm){

    elm.value = crystalNumbers.shift();

  });
}

generateCrystalNumber();
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer">
    <img id = "crystal1" src="assets/images/crystal1.jpg" alt="crystal1">
    <img id = "crystal2" src="assets/images/crystal2.jpg" alt="crystal2">
    <img id = "crystal3" src="assets/images/crystal3.jpg" alt="crystal3">
    <img id = "crystal4" src="assets/images/crystal4.jpg" alt="crystal4">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// To associate a random number in image's data attribute
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).data('data-random-Number', generateCrystalNumber());
}

function generateCrystalNumber(){
    //for (var i = 0; i<4; i++){ -- For loop is not needed
       return (Math.floor(Math.random()*12) + 1);
       // crystalNumbers.push(crystalNumvar); 
    //}
}
```

Comment: That for loop in your generateCrystalNumber() is not needed though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a solution where on clicking the image, you want to show a random image due to random number generation.
Below code can be a start.

1. Code gets image elements references and pushed them to `imgElems` array.
2. It calls `generateCrystalNumber()` so that random numbers are generated and stored in the array
3. Click event is registered on `imgContainer` which is a parent div for all the elements.
4. Inside event handler, the code figures out which image was clicked and changes the src attribute by reading from the random number array.

**Note**: You may want to tweak the logic further to reset the random numbers as per your requirements

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var crystalNumbers = [];
        var imgElems = [];
        var path = "assets/images/crystal";
        imgElems.push(document.getElementById('crystal1'));
        imgElems.push(document.getElementById('crystal2'));
        imgElems.push(document.getElementById('crystal3'));
        imgElems.push(document.getElementById('crystal4'));

        generateCrystalNumber();

        function generateCrystalNumber() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                var crystalNumvar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
                crystalNumbers.push(crystalNumvar);
                
            }

        }
        
        $('body').on('click', '#imgContainer',function (e) {
            var id = e.target.id;
            $('#' + id).attr('src', path + crystalNumbers[id.slice(-1)-1] + ".jpg");

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgContainer">
    <img id = "crystal1" src="assets/images/crystal1.jpg" alt="crystal1">
    <img id = "crystal2" src="assets/images/crystal2.jpg" alt="crystal2">
    <img id = "crystal3" src="assets/images/crystal3.jpg" alt="crystal3">
    <img id = "crystal4" src="assets/images/crystal4.jpg" alt="crystal4">
  </div>
```